# Ajuda com Array Multidimensional em PHP?

Tags: php, array, array-multidimensional

Estou lendo algumas `API`, e deparei com uma situação com `array`, que estou tendo um pouco de dificuldade, procurei bastante no fórum antes de perguntar, porém, como tenho pouca experiência estou quebrando a cabeça.

A estrutura da API vem dessa forma:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array(
            [cidade] => Rio de Janeiro
            [estado] => RJ
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cidade] => São Paulo
            [estado] => SP
        )

)
```

Eu preciso pegar o conteúdo de cima e criar índices para transformar em um `array` único, como abaixo:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cidade] => Rio de Janeiro
            [estado] => RJ
        )
    
    [1] => Array
        (
            [cidade] => São Paulo
            [estado] => SP
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode utilizar um [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-map.php) para a construção de um novo [array](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php) pelo modelo inicial, é um [array](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php) principal e dentro de cada posição outro [array](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php), com uma simples função de mudança pode ser feito um [array](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php) que representa as informações com todas as posições, exemplo:

```
<?php

    $datas = array(
        array(array('cidade' => 'Rio de Janeiro', 'estado' => 'RJ')),
        array(array('cidade' => 'São Paulo', 'estado' => 'SP'))
    );

    function organize($item) {
        return $item[0];    
    }

    $newDatas = array_map('organize', $datas);
```

nessa função `function organize($item){}`, por exemplo pode ser aplicada outras regras para cada item contido nesse `array`, no caso apliquei a regra que está na sua pergunta.

Comment: muito obrigado novic. me ajudou bastante!